# Why are these two forms for an operator equivalent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, notation

According to a paper I am reading (https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08448. roughly page 8), an operator $K(t)$ is define as follows:

$$ K(t) = i\hbar\sum_n | \dot{n}_0(t)\rangle \langle n_0(t)| \tag{1} \label{eq:1}$$

Later, it gives another form as follows:

$$ K(t) = i\hbar\sum_n \frac{dP_n(t)}{dt}P_n(t)\tag{2}\label{eq:2}$$

where $P_n$ is defined as $|n_0(t)\rangle \langle n_0(t)|$.
However, I find that that Eq. (\ref{eq:2}) has extra terms due to application of the chain rule:

$$ K(t) = i\hbar\sum_n \Big(|\dot{n}_0(t)\rangle \langle n_0(t)| + |n_0(t)\rangle \langle \dot{n}_0(t)|\Big)\Big(|n_0(t)\rangle \langle n_0(t)|\Big)\tag{3}\label{eq:3}$$,

and so does not equal Eq. (\ref{eq:1}). Where is the error in my reasoning? In case it's necessary, $n_0$ satisfies a parallel transport condition written as $\langle n_0(t)|  \dot{n}_0(0)\rangle$ = 0

Comment: @march The problem is that the orthogonality condition only holds for $t=0$ in the $\dot n$ part.

Comment: @march Yes, they are normalized. Then, why does the second pair of terms cancel out? It doesn't quite satisfy the parallel transport condition.

Comment: Is the sum over $n$ supposed to mean a sum over $n_0$, or to imply a sum over $n_0$ or what? What is the point of the subscript zero?

Comment: @hft For all intents and purposes, you may ignore the subscript 0. It comes from an iterative process in the paper, and I should have left it out to avoid confusion. I am also going to include the link to the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08448. It is on page 8.

Comment: Which paper? How is $n_0(t)$ defined?

Comment: I think you just use the parallel transport condition evaluated at $t=0$. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$ K(t) = i\hbar\sum_n \Big(|\dot{n}_0(t)\rangle \langle n_0(t)| + |n_0(t)\rangle \langle \dot{n}_0(t)|\Big)\Big(|n_0(t)\rangle \langle n_0(t)|\Big)\tag{3}$$,
>
> ...In case it's necessary, $n_0$ satisfies a parallel transport condition written as $\langle n_0(t)|  \dot{n}_0(0)\rangle$ = 0

If the ket is normalized, then the problem boils down to showing that the quoted parallel transport condition:
$$
\langle \dot n(t)|n(0)\rangle = 0\tag{A}
$$
implies that
$$
\langle \dot n(t)|n(t)\rangle = 0\;.
$$

---

I assume that Eq. (A) holds for all $t$. Therefore, it holds for $t=0$:
$$
\langle \dot n(0)|n(0)\rangle = 0\tag{B}
$$

I will assume there is no explicit time-dependence and so:
$$
e^{-iHt}|n(0)\rangle = |n(t)\rangle\;.\tag{C}
$$

Next, observe that
$$
\langle \dot n(t)|n(t)\rangle = \langle \dot n(t)|e^{-iHt}|n(0)\rangle = \langle \dot n(0)|n(0)\rangle = 0\;,
$$
by Eq. (B).

---

**Update:**

I don't know the solution in the general time-dependent case.

Comment: @Idieh (1/2) I suspect it's more complicated than this, because the context involves a time-dependent hamiltonian $H(t)$, and the paper is talking about adiabaticity.  I cannot tell (from the paper, or by hand) if the equivalence between the two forms of $K$ is *exact* or if the assumption of adiabaticity is required to make this approximation.  In addition, because of the time-dependent $H$ and the pulling-out of geometric phases from the instantaneous eigenstates of $H$, it's pretty unclear what $|\dot{n}(t)\rangle$ even *means*.

Comment: @Idieh  (2/2) Does it mean $\frac{d}{dt}|n(t)\rangle$? In that case, it's equal to $\frac{1}{i\hbar}H(t)|n(t)\rangle$, and I can't see how that matches the calculation in this post. However, I think $|n_0(t)\rangle$ actually already has some geometric phases pulled out (to parallel transport it), so again, the calculation is more complicated.  Anyway, the point is, I can't see how $\langle \dot{n}(t)|e^{-iHt} = \langle \dot{n}(0)|$ under all of this context.

Comment: Yes, it means $\frac{d}{dt}|n(t)\rangle$, but you can call it whatever you want, say $|\chi(t)\rangle$. You can see that $|\dot n(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt}|\dot n(0)\rangle$ from the expression you wrote: $\frac{1}{i\hbar}H(t)|n(t)\rangle$. Since $H(t)=H$ does not depend on time explicitly (and we are in the schrodinger picture), $|n(t)\rangle=e^{-iHt}|n(0)\rangle$ and $H$ commutes with $e^{-iHt}$. $|\dot n(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{i\hbar}H(t)|n(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{i\hbar}H e^{-iHt}|n(0)\rangle = e^{-iHt}\frac{1}{i\hbar}H|n(0)\rangle= e^{-iHt}\frac{1}{i\hbar}H(0)|n(0)\rangle=e^{-iHt}|\dot n(0)\rangle$

Comment: @march See above. Sorry, I ran out of space in the comment so tagging you in this comment below

Comment: @march wait. you are not tagging me in your comments, you are tagging OP. Did you mean to comment on the question or on this answer?

Comment: Well, that was meant for both of you, really. What you've written might be correct; I just can't figure out if it is or not.  In the paper, $|n_0(t)\rangle$ looks something like $e^{i\theta(t)}|psi_n(t)\rangle$, where $|psi_n(t)\rangle$ is an *instantaneous* eigenvector of $H(t)$ at time $t$, and hence the $|psi_n(t)\rangle$ does *not* mean time-evolution of $|psi_n(0)\rangle$ under the Hamiltonian. Except, they assume adiabaticity, in which case $|psi_n(t)\rangle$ is *approximately* equal to the time evolution of $|psi_n(0)\rangle$ to time $t$. So you can see why I'm having trouble.

Comment: @march OK, I updated my answer to account for the general case of a hamiltonian that explicitly depends on time

Comment: @ hft I am confused on this point: $U(t)|\dot n(0)\rangle = |\dot n(t)\rangle$. I am having difficulty seeing why this is true for time-dependent Hamiltonian. It seems to me that $|\dot n(t)\rangle$ is defined as $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (U(t)|n(0)\rangle)$ . Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Idieh Hmm. Yeah. Then I guess I am not sure how to show this in the general case. Maybe it is not true in general, but is somehow true for your specific case of interest? Or maybe it is only true up to some correction the authors ignore?